# How to access lists in Rcpp?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I want to use Rcpp to make certain parts of my code more efficient. I have a main R function in which my objects are defined, in this R functions I have several rcpp functions that use the r data objects as inputs. This is one example of an rcpp function that is called in the R-function:

```
void calculateClusters ( List order, 
                                 NumericVector maxorder,
                                 List rank,
                                 double lambda, 
                                 int nbrClass, 
                                 NumericVector nbrExamples) {

  int current, i;

  for ( current = 0; current < nbrClass; current ++ ) {
    maxorder [current] = 0;

    for ( i = 0; i < nbrExamples [ current ]; i++ ) {
        order[ current ][i] = ( int ) ( rank[ current ][i] / lambda ) - 1;
    }

      if ( order[ current ][i] > maxorder[ current ] ) {
        maxorder[ current ] = order[ current ][i];
      }
    }
  }
```

This function calculates the maximum number of clusters for each class. In native c++ coding I would define my `List` as an `int**` and my `NumericVector` as `int*`. However in Rcpp this gives an error. I know the fault lies in the subsetting of these `Lists` (I handled them the same way as `int**`).

My question is how can I transform these `int**` succesfully into `List`, without loosing flexibility. For example the `List order` and `distance` have the structure `order[[1]][1:500], order[[2]][1:500]`, so this would be exactly the same as `int**` in c++ where it would be `order[1][1:500], order[2][1:500]`. If there are 3 classes the `order` and the `distance` `List` change to order `order[[1]][1:500], order[[2]][1:500], order[[3]][1:500]`. How can I do this in Rcpp?

Comment: Here is an example of handling lists: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12734655/1412059

Comment: What error are you getting? You should be able to subset the `List` the way you’ve described, except that you need to tell C++ that the type of `rank[current]` is *also* a subsettable element (list? vector?).

Answer (score 3):

Briefly:

- [Example from the Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/faster-data-frame-creation/)
- [Example from the Rcpp Examples package on CRAN](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppexamples/blob/master/src/ListExample.cpp)