# Accessing Named List Elements in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I would like to access a named list element by name in Rcpp

In R

```
> b = list(bgroups=c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0))
> b$bgroups
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

Then when trying to access this in Rcpp
I have tried:

```
cppFunction(
  "
void f(List & b){
 std::vector<int> c(10) = as<std::vector<int>> b['bgroups'];
}
  "
)
```

...

```
NumericVector groupings = b['bgroups'];
```

...

```
NumericVector groupings(10) = b(4);
```

But to no avail.

I've reviewed Dirk's many helpful answers, but have not been able to make the connection
https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppexamples/blob/master/src/ListExample.cpp

[How to handle list in R to Rcpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719334/how-to-handle-list-in-r-to-rcpp/12734655#12734655)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if I understand your question completely but have you tired below in your CppFunction.

```
NumericVector Bgroups = as<NumericVector>(b["bgroups"]);
```

Comment: Yep. OP tries to index a `std::vector` which is not a named vector.

Comment: Tried NumericVector split(const List & b){  NumericVector c= as<NumericVector>(b['bgroups']);  return c;}")  but that caused my R session to terminate

Answer (score 0):

You already mention the [source code for `ListExample.cpp`](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppexamples/blob/master/src/ListExample.cpp), if you also look at the [source for the R complement `RcppListExample.R`](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppexamples/blob/master/R/RcppListExample.R) it really should become clear.

Your question is also not complete and reproducible so it makes it harder to help you.

Comment: Thanks. I tried NumericVector split(const List & b){NumericVector c= as<NumericVector>(b['bgroups']);  return c;} but that forced my R session to quit.

Comment: I revised the question for clarity. Could I trouble you to take a look?