# Why does this make my R session abort?

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm trying to implement named-list calling in Rcpp

in R

```
b<-list("bgroups"=c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0))
> b$bgroups
[1] 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0

cppFunction(
  "
NumericVector split(Rcpp::List & b){
  Rcpp::NumericVector c= b['bgroups'];
  return c;
}")

split(b)
```

But this causes my R session to abort.

I'm trying to implement this procedure as illustrated in one of Dirk's presentations, but I'm missing something.

[image]

[This is an extension of my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51258206/accessing-named-list-elements-in-rcpp)

Comment: You need double quote `"` in the C++ code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following works:

```
b<-list("bgroups"=c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0))
b$bgroups
#[1] 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0

Rcpp::cppFunction(
  '
NumericVector split(Rcpp::List & b){
  Rcpp::NumericVector c = b["bgroups"];
  return c;
}')

split(b)
#[1] 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

In C++, `'` is used to quote a character, while `"` is used to quote strings. My compiler warns me about this:

```
warning: character constant too long for its type
   Rcpp::NumericVector c= b['bgroups'];
                            ^~~~~~~~~
```

Generally it is a good idea to take compiler warnings seriously.